# Help with a regular expression to capture numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to capture the price out of the following string:

`Price: 30`.

I need the `30` here, so I figured I'd use the following regex:

`([0-9]+)$`

This works in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/VDoqGDYQAK), but it returns `null` when I try it in my javascript.

```
console.log(values[1]);
// Price: 100
var price = values[1].match('/([0-9]+)$/g');
// null
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var price = values[1].match(/([0-9]+)$/g);
```

JavaScript supports RegExp literals, you don't need quotes and delimiters.
`.match(/\d+$/)` should behave the same, by the way.

See also: [MDN - Creating a Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Keep in mind there are simpler ways of getting this data. For example:

```
var tokens = values[1].split(': ');
var price = tokens[1];
```

You can also split by a single space, and probably want to add some validation.

Comment: Doh. No quotes in match(). Thanks ;D

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use this?

```
var matches = a.match(/\d+/);
```

then you can consume the first element (or last)

my suggestion is to avoid using $ in the end because there might be a space in the end.

Comment: Okay. Can you explain what that actually means? I'm new to the whole regex deal, so I was just trying in rubular till I got something that worked, haha.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

`var price = values[1].match('([0-9]+)$');`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you escaped the open-perens and therefore the regex is looking for "(90".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put quotes around the regular expression in JavaScript.